# Azure Remote Debugging: Failed to enable remote debuggingException from HRESULT: 0x89710023

Tags: debugging, azure, remote-debugging

I'm getting a strange error: '**Failed to enable remote debuggingException from HRESULT: 0x89710023**' while I'm trying to debug remotely Azure Website. I'm using VS2013 with Azure Tools v.2.2. There are a lot of people who are getting this error here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx but there is no working solution.

**Resolved**

I've managed to resolve this as installed Azure Tools 2.2 on a new machine with fresh installed VS 2013. Not sure what caused the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't very forthright.

I found the answer from Twitter https://twitter.com/martinhelgesen/status/410363288132657152

Basically just open up ports 4016 and 4018 and things should work.

Comment: Strange.  I opened ports 4016 and 4018 and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you temporarily disable your Windows Firewall to see if that's the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I found that if my site name contains a - sign, the remote debugger will not work.
The remote debugger worked when I switched to a site name without the '-' sign.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I can't seem to authenticate to run remote debugging on my web job and I'm starting to think this is the issue...