# Error when trying to remotely debug an azure website (HRESULT: 0x89710023)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm having troubles enabling remote debugging on sharepoint online. I have 2 machines, my local machine (Windows 8.1) and my development server(Windows Server 2008 R2). On my development server I first tried remote debugging using Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, as described here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug.

When this didn't work I tried doing exactly the same thing on my local machine, which has Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate) update 1 and the latest windows azure sdk (2.3). This worked perfectly. Thinking upgrading to visual studio 2013 would solve my problem I've installed 2013 (Premium) on my dev server, next to 2010 and 2012. After installing and updating everything for 2 hours however, I came to the conclusion that I received the same error as on VS 2012.

Googling came up with a few interesting causes for this bug: sitenames longer than 20 characters or sitenames containing hyphens. This is not the case. Then I verified port settings, the dev server has no active firewall but I wanted to exclude any possibilities. And low and behold, both telnetting from my local machine as my dev server to ports 4016 and 4018 of my azurewebsites.net url worked.

Are there any other solutions for this bug? Since debugging locally is not an option (sharepoint provider hosted app for project online) this is very inconvenient.

Thanks,

UPDATE: Deploying the site as a cloud service works, and so does remote debugging them. However, we would like to stay with azure web sites for now..

I know this is a duplicate of [Azure Remote Debugging: Failed to enable remote debuggingException from HRESULT: 0x89710023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188108/azure-remote-debugging-failed-to-enable-remote-debuggingexception-from-hresult); but none of the solutions there or on twitter were of any use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure Remote Debugging: Failed to enable remote debuggingException from HRESULT: 0x89710023](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188108/azure-remote-debugging-failed-to-enable-remote-debuggingexception-from-hresult)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Azure Remote Debugging: Failed to enable remote debuggingException from HRESULT: 0x89710023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188108/azure-remote-debugging-failed-to-enable-remote-debuggingexception-from-hresult)

I think this has to do with blocked ports 4016 and 4018

Comment: I'm able to telnet to those ports, so this can't be the problem.